# How to Disable mod_pagespeed on a specific type of URLs

Tags: nginx, permalinks, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, amp-html

i've **mod_pagespeed** installed on my **nginx** server and i love it.

Recently, i installed AMP posts in my website and all permalink now have the `/amp/` at the end of the URL.

The problem is that mod_pagespeed (at this time) doesn't support AMP tag, so the console show me some errors. But when i insert `?PageSpeed=off` at the end of the amp URLs, **AMP is validated**.

So, i'd like, if it's possible, to deactivate mod_pagespeed only for all URLs that have the /amp/ at the end.

The permalink structure is: `https://www.example.com/postname/`

The permalink structure for AMP is: `https://www.example.com/postname/amp/`

So, mod_pagespeed should work only on the first permalink structure.

The code that i tried to put into mod_pagespeed is the follow:

```
pagespeed Disallow “https://*example.com/*/amp/*”;
```

It isn't refuse by the module, but it don't turn off the pagespeed module on the AMP posts. Can you help me about that?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Would love to get an answer to this also, as PageSpeed is causing loads of AMP validation errors for me too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this in your pagespeed.conf file:

```
pagespeed Disallow */amp/*;
```